# ELMAH Exceptions in 3-layer application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

In a 3-layer application working on, I have the business layer talking to DB, validating data, and sending back results to Controllers.

Calls to DB are wrapped inside a try/catch. Is it recommend to throw exceptions at that layer? Will ELMAH catch it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the situation is exceptional (ie. cannot connect to DB). If the exception propagates up then ELMAH will catch it.

Do not use exception for 'business' errors, like couldn't find a certain record in the table. Returning `null` in this situation is probably better.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. What I am planning to do is simply not use "try/catch" catch business layer, leave it to Controller to try/catch, log error, display decent message to user. Sounds good?